# PR2: basestation network manager no longer valid

Tags: ros-diamondback, ubuntu-precise, ubuntu, pr2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I'm trying to recover a PR2 in my research lab. It hasn't seen a lot of use in the past few years. I am having issues with the basestation regarding the network manager no longer being valid and I'm trying to find the recover ISO (v0.6.0>); it was last upgrade to Ubuntu precise running diamondback according to records and I don't want to mess with the configurations without a recovery option. As it stands the base station can't communicate with the network. I have tried using CloneZilla to make a copy of present state but it runs into bitmap errors.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions on recovery.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/361380/pr2:-basestation-network-manager-no-longer-valid/) by [shane113h](https://answers.ros.org/users/59268/shane113h/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2020-09-11

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-09-11**:
@fergs seems like someone with some experience getting old "forgotten" robots to work again, perhaps he has an idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I don't know if there was ever an ISO image for the PR2 or basestation - I think we might have just installed regular old Ubuntu (probably server edition) and then installed a bunch of custom debians. I'm not sure where those debians might be hosted today - but the sources are here: https://github.com/pr2-debs/pr2-basestation. That whole organization has a bunch of deb sources for the robot as well.

---

Originally posted by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) with karma: 13902 on 2020-09-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [shane113h](https://answers.ros.org/users/59268/shane113h/) on 2020-09-16**:
Thank you very much for this!